# Drawing lines between specific points in two images

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have two images. For some specific points I know their coordinates on the two images, how can I draw lines between those points and plot a figure showing the two images along with the matching lines?

I actually didn't know where to start here. That's why I didn't show any code yet. Would `matplotlib` benefit me in this case?

**EDIT** This is an example of what I'm expecting (the image is taken from, [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/dc/dc3/tutorial_py_matcher.html)):

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: we should see how should **look** the expected result

Comment: Sure, I have added an example.

Comment: A good place to start might be to display your two images on two subplots. and make the connections with a [`ConnectionPatch`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.ConnectionPatch.html#matplotlib.patches.ConnectionPatch). You might want to give that a go and come back here with any questions you have if you can't get it working.

Answer (score -1):

What you are searching for is directly in your example you just have to use the function. If you don't know what matches contains you can use the example and look into it.

```
 img3 = cv2.drawMatches(img1,kp1,img2,kp2,matches[:20], flags=2,outImg = img1)
```

My full code:

```
if method is "ORB":
        #Compute keypoints for both images
        kp1,des1 = self.computeORB(img1)
        kp2,des2 = self.computeORB(img2)  
        #===================================================================
        # for i,j in zip(kp1,kp2):
        #     print("KP1:",i.pt)  
        #     print("KP2:",j.pt)   
        #===================================================================
        #use brute force matcher for matching descriptor1 and descriptor2
        bf = cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_HAMMING, crossCheck=True)
        # Match descriptors.
        matches = bf.match(des1,des2)

        # Sort them in the order of their distance.
        matches = sorted(matches, key = lambda x:x.distance)
        self.filterMatches(matches)

        # Draw first 10 matches.
        img3 = cv2.drawMatches(img1,kp1,img2,kp2,matches[:20], flags=2,outImg = img1)

        #show result
        cv2.imshow("Matches",img3)
        cv2.waitKey(0)

def computeORB(self,img):
    #Initiate ORB detector
    orb = cv2.ORB_create()

    #find keypoints
    kp = orb.detect(img,None)

    #compute despriptor
    kp, des = orb.compute(img,kp)
    # draw only keypoints location,not size and orientation
    img2 = cv2.drawKeypoints(img, kp, None, color=(0,255,0), flags=0)
    #plt.imshow(img2), plt.show()

    return kp,des
```

note that you need cv2 contribution version if you are using newer python versions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I'm not trying to use OpenCV for my task.